# Call a Delegate after Thread execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to call a SQL command that may take 3+ minutes to run.

Clearly I don't just want to call it and wait for it to finish.

What I want to do is create a thread and execute it within it.

I also don't want to use the "Are we there yet?" method and would prefer the thread to call a delegate in the calling thread that it has completed.

So I have this as the main thread;

```
public Thread Process()
{
    worker = new Worker { date = date, dc = dc, despatchProcess = despatchProcess };
    workerThread = new Thread(worker.process);
    workerThread.Start();
    return workerThread;
}
```

So inside worker I want it to call a delegate within this main thread.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: it'd be nice to know why there was a downvote given this is a legit question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best option is to use a `Task`, not a thread.  You can then add a continuation on the task (or the new `async`/`await` syntax) to run code when the task completes.

```
public Task Process()
{
    worker = new Worker { date = date, dc = dc, despatchProcess = despatchProcess };
    return Task.Factory.StartNew( () => worker.process() );
}
```

The caller can then write:

```
Task work = Process();
work.ContinueWith(t => 
{
    // Run code here when work is done
});
```

If you need the code that runs when this completes to be run in the main UI thread, you can use:

```
work.ContinueWith(t => 
{
    // Run code here when work is done
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `async` and `await` the high level docs are here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx I'll try to find some simple examples because that's just way too much information.

EDIT:

This is a better example; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx
You basically just need to specify your delegate `await`'s the method making the sql call.

Comment: async/await requires C# 5 on VS 2012, please don't suggest solutions that require the latest technology without adding that caveat, otherwise it wastes peoples time that have earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent enough version of .NET the other answers using `Task` and `async/await` are perfectly good options. Otherwise I'd probably go with a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) in which you can listen to the 'RunWorkerCompleted' event and optionally handle cancellation.